# Импорт svg в react

Tags: reactjs

я делаю так

```
import Ptm_report_Logo from '../../../assets/icons/ptmreport.svg';

        <IconStyled>
            <img src={Ptm_report_Logo} height={25} width={25} />
        </IconStyled>
```

Путь подчеркивается красным и получаю ошибку "Cannot find module '../../../assets/icons/ptmreport.svg' or its corresponding type declarations."
кто знает как это можно победить?

Comment: Вот статейка на эту тему... https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.fb21b4e1-6582ec45-48bde397-74722d776562/https/www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-import-svgs-in-react-and-vite

Comment: Тут есть такая тема... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296499/how-to-display-svg-icons-svg-files-in-ui-using-react-component

Comment: Больше похоже на проблему тайп скрипта. Скорее всего у вас необьявлено как должны быть типизированы .svg модули. Что-то типа declare module "*.svg". Обычно возвращаемым значением убдет строка путь после компиляции вебпака. Так же на всякий случай убедитесь что у вас в вебпак конфиге есть нужный лоадер для .svg файлов.

Answer (score 0):

SVG в React можно импортировать прямо из svg файла, и вставлять в вёрстку как React компонент. Для этого его надо импортировать следующим образом:

```
import { ReactComponent as PtmReportLogo } from '/путь/к/ptmreport.svg';
```

Дальше используем в return компонента:

```
<PtmReportLogo />
```

Можно пробросить в него класс чтобы в стилях управлять размерами. Вставка svg таким способом в том числе позволяет перекрасить его при помощи css (например при hover-е или других условиях)

Comment: так пробовал, не работает

Comment: в комментах нашел ссылку, там куча пример, помог такой пример - создаешь tsx компонент из которого возвращаешь svg, потом его импортируешь и используешь

Comment: @АлексейМелентьев пусть svg лежит в той же папке в которой файл куда импортишь. У меня работает. Либо ты на Next-е а не на React...